# Is it OK to separate fire and structural analyses when analyzing a fire induced building collapse?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, failure-analysis

This is from NIST NCSTAR 1-6

[image]

It seems to me there are problems with this approach. The heat distribution depends on fire spread and ventilation paths, which in turn depend on the shape of tjr imterior structure. And precisely thus is expected to change a lot during the course of this fire, in the form of floor sagging and collapse.

Comment: Everything is an approximation.  Whether something is OK depends on the error bounds of that approximation and whether you have erred on the side of caution.

Comment: @Abel seems like a rather large compromise here. An internal collapse can start a fire on a whole new floor. It can also smother a fire and spare critical structures.

Comment: So do your structural analysis as if the thermal conditions are far worse than any thermal analysis would ever dictate.  If the results say your structure is not good enough under those conditions, go back to the drawing board.